# manipulate directories using cut or awk?

Tags: linux, bash, command-line, awk, command

I am processing some directories in Linux, and I am trying to manipulate the file names, here's my case

```
grep 'string' | awk '{print $2$3}'
```

and I get the following

```
dir1/another-directory/even-another-directory/file1.jpeg
dir1/another-directory/even-another-directory/fiiile2.jpeg
dir1/another-directory/even-another-directory/filee4.jpeg
dir1/another-directory/even-another-directory/fileee1.jpeg
```

I am trying to take the last part of these files (anything after the slash), so that I get a list like this, in a CSV file maybe?

```
file1.jpeg
fiiile2.jpeg
filee4.jpeg
fileee1.jpeg
```

would awk or cut be able to do that? I know this is a very basic question, but I couldn't find something related online so far.

Thanks,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

do everything with awk:

```
awk '/string/{x=$2$3;sub(/.*\//,"",x);print x}'
```

Answer (score 1):

Drop the `grep` and do the match in `awk` and use `xargs` to call `basename` on each file for stripping the leading directories:

```
awk '/string/{print $2$3}' | xargs -n1 basename
```

Comment: Just curiosity, but why didn't you do all the job with `awk` instead of creating an additional subshell?

Comment: Because it thought I the introduction to the tool `basename` was more appropriate.